# PHP How to use a property declared in another method?

Tags: php, oop

I recently started with PHP Object Oriented and I cannot seem to get this done. In a method I declare a property which I want to use in another method, but I get an error: **Undefined property: Database::$test**.

```
class Database {

    public function connect() {
        $connection = 'hoi';
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        echo $this->connection;
    }

}

$db = new Database();
$db->connect();
$db->disconnect();
```

Again, I'm new at OOP. I tried using **global** with the scope of a function in mind which would make sense in a regular function, but I just get another error when I use that.

Comment: You can't declare a property in a method. In fact, in your code you have no properties at all, though you attempt to use one in your `disconnect()` function

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not exactly. If `connect()` set `$this->connection` it would work, but it's not the best/recommended way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public function connect() {
    $connection = 'hoi';
}
```

is simply defining a local variable, not assigning as a property in the object. It should be:

```
    $this->connection = 'hoi';
```

Answer (score 7):

You have declared connection as a variable, not a property.  This is what you want.

```
class Database {

    private $connection;

    public function connect() {
        $this->connection = 'hoi';
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        echo $this->connection;
    }

}
```

Read the [PHP.net documentation on classes and objects](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: There is a pretty good tutorial on php.net about this:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php